# AlertDialog to appear once not everytime device rotated

Tags: android, android-studio, android-alertdialog, onsaveinstancestate

I have a warning alertdialog that appears when a user starts an activity. It reappears though if the device is rotated. I am using a dialog fragment and have tried a few different approaches. Do I need to create something in the onSavedInstanceState in the fragment to achieve this or is there another way?

Fragment

```
public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {




    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog( Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        Log.d(TAG, "Alert Dialog");

        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.warning_title));

        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.medical_advice));


        builder.setPositiveButton("I understand", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });

        return builder.create();

    }
    @Override
    public void onCancel(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onCancel(dialog);
        Log.d(TAG,"onCancel:called");

    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        Log.d(TAG,"On dismiss called");
    }
    @Override
   public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);


    }
```

Main activity method

```
  public void showDialog(){
        AlertDialogFragment alertDialog= new AlertDialogFragment();
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"Fragment Alert Dialog");

    }
```

Comment: You should know that when device rotates, activity restarts so use a view model storing a value to show the dialog or not, and before showing the dialog, access the value and decide accordingly. Or you can use `SharedPreferences` to save a boolean to false when first showing the `AlertDialog` and check it. Reset it in previous activity or when the app restarts.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the dialog showing state in a boolean in your activity and save and restore it on activity recreations:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean mIsDialogShown = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...

        if (savedInstanceState != null) mIsDialogShown = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isDialogShown", false);
        if (!mIsDialogShown) showDialog();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean("isDialogShown", mIsDialogShown);
    }

    public void showDialog() {
        mIsDialogShown = true;
        AlertDialogFragment alertDialog = new AlertDialogFragment();
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"Fragment Alert Dialog");
    }
}
```

Comment: Had been trying something like this all day with no luck. Did try your suggestion word for word but still the same outcome so not sure what the issue is. Everytime the device rotates the alert dialog reappears

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get this working by adding

```
if (savedInstanceState==null)
     showDialog();
```

Not sure why it works now as I thought it was already represented in the code but for now it is working.